# linux tools that deal with metadata

Tags: pdf, metadata, ffprobe, exiftool, djvu

there is pdfinfo for PDFs, exifinfo for images, ffprobe for multimedia and so on. are the a collection or a standardized toolset for extracting filetype dependent(like pdf, image, doc, odt) metadata of all files in linux?

or even distinct tool that are file-format specific for most common file types like ppt, epub and other file types we commonly find in internet downloads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exiftool can extract metadata from more than just images.  See [Supported File Types](https://exiftool.org/#supported).